# Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to get some data with GraphQL by sending over a json web token but the result I get is an error.

This is the part of my resolvers, that is addressed by the error message.

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: async (token) => {
            try {
                const payload = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
                if (payload.userId) {
                    const me = await User.findById(payload.userId);
                    return me;
                } else {
                    throw { message: 'Invalid token!' };
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return error.message;
            }
        },
```

...

The error reads:

```
"errors": [
{
  "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.name.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 3,
      "column": 5
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "me",
    "name"
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
```

...

The typeDef for user:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
}
```

and

```
extend type Query {
    me(token: String!): User
}
```

Where is my mistake!?

Thank you!

Comment: can you please share your typedef/schema for user for better debugging?

Comment: I have provided some more information

Comment: record from db had empty `name`?

Comment: nope, the database is filled

Comment: it's because in type User, you have marked all the fields mandatory in response. So, if one of the field is coming null or undefined from db, so graphql will throw error as it is a mandatory field and it is not present in response.

Comment: can you please share the db entry?

Comment: ok, but why is the user emtpy/not set?

Comment: please verify payload.userId. Are you sure you are getting userId in this?

Comment: the token is undefined ... what did I do wrong?

Comment: token should be taken from args, one of resolver arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: async (_, { token }) => {
            try {
                const payload = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
                if (payload) {
                    const me = await User.findById(payload.userId);
                    return me;
                } else {
                    throw { message: 'Invalid token!' };
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return error.message;
            }
        }
```

...

this was the solution. I had `(token) => { ... }` but it should be  `(_, { token }) => { ... }` in the me-function!

Comment: You shouldn't return `error.message`. Just omit the catch, or if you want to obfuscate the original error, throw another error inside the catch. If you return a String or another non-error object, GraphQL will assume you're returning a User object and try to coerce the value accordingly.

Comment: mmh, thanks for your advice.

Comment: but what should I replace the `error.message` with?!?

Comment: Just omit the try/catch

Comment: thanks! :D now i am well prepared!